# Trouble with has_many :through => association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Caution:  I am a 4 week old at programming. I am having trouble with a has_many :through => relationship between my Neighborhood and Cta_train models.

Here are my models:

```
class CtaTrain < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :Ctaline
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
  has_many :neighborhoods, :through => :CtaLocation, :foreign_key => :neighborhood_id
  has_many :CtaLocations

end

class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :geopoints
  has_many :listings
  has_many :properties
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
  has_many :CtaTrains, :through => :CtaLocation, :foreign_key => :cta_train_id
  has_many :CtaLocations
end

class CtaLocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :neighborhood
  belongs_to :CtaTrain

end
```

When I try to do this:

```
neighborhood.CtaTrains
```

I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the association :CtaLocation in model Neighborhood):

I have been slogging through this for several hours now....I have tried many iterations of ideas from stackoverflow....what I show above feels like the closest solution, but obviously still not working.  Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not following Rails conventions by using lowercase/underscore for your symbols. Class names have to be CamelCase but you should be doing the following everywhere else:

```
class CtaTrain < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :cta_line
  has_and_belongs_to_many :searches
  has_many :neighborhoods, :through => :cta_locations, :foreign_key => :neighborhood_id
  has_many :cta_locations

end
```

*Update: You should also be using :cta_locations (plural) in your has many through

Comment: YES!!!  Your update did the trick. I have :CtaLocations and it works.  I don't know what to say about the naming convention....when I change to lowercase/underscore it breaks with undefined methods.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Not sure about the undefined methods, but I would highly recommend following the standard conventions, especially if you plan on working on the project with other Rails devs. The Rails Guide is awesome and uses those conventions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I have tried to fix the naming conventions and I am running into some problems.  I started a new question on naming conventions in case anyone else is having similar problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553768/trouble-with-rails-naming-conventions