# Trouble with rails naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, has-many-through

I think I have followed the rails naming conventions in my app.  But when I am in the terminal testing code I am coming across some errors that go against naming conventions.  Here is my terminal session:

```
irb(main):010:0> a = _
=> #<Neighborhood id: 24, name: "Lincoln Park", created_at: "2011-12-03 20:29:00", updated_at: "2011-12-03 21:08:47", minlat: 41.91092, maxlat: 41.925658, minlng: -87.648761, maxlng: -87.636117>
irb(main):011:0> a.cta_trains
NoMethodError: undefined method `cta_trains' for #<Neighborhood:0x007fd666ee61e8>
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
```

Now when I try a.CtaTrains:

```
irb(main):012:0> a.CtaTrains
  CtaTrain Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cta_trains".* FROM "cta_trains" INNER JOIN "cta_locations" ON "cta_trains"."id" = "cta_locations"."CtaTrain_id" WHERE "cta_locations"."neighborhood_id" = 24
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cta_locations.CtaTrain_id: SELECT "cta_trains".* FROM "cta_trains" INNER JOIN "cta_locations" ON "cta_trains"."id" = "cta_locations"."CtaTrain_id" WHERE "cta_locations"."neighborhood_id" = 24
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cta_locations.CtaTrain_id: SELECT "cta_trains".* FROM "cta_trains" INNER JOIN "cta_locations" ON "cta_trains"."id" = "cta_locations"."CtaTrain_id" WHERE "cta_locations"."neighborhood_id" = 24
```

From my models:

```
class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cta_trains, :through => :cta_locations
  has_many :cta_locations, :foreign_key => :neighborhood_id

end 

class CtaTrain < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :neighborhoods, :through => :cta_locations
  has_many :cta_locations, :foreign_key => :cta_train_id

end

class CtaLocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :neighborhood
belongs_to :cta_train

end
```

I am at a standstill, stuck, banging my head against the wall, etc.  Any help would be fabulous.

Rails noobie here....as if this point is not obvious.....

Comment: Do you get the same problems when running `bundle exec rails console` instead of `irb` ?

Comment: Not at all. It works.  You are the man.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Cool, added as an answer so you can mark correct to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that you appear to be in IRB... Instead, I'd try to stay in the rails console when working with your active-record classes.

so start that with

```
bundle exec rails console
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a junction table. See the association `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

The junction table will store the links between a certain `Neighbourhood` and a certain `CtaTrain`. Here, it's CtaLocation but if you don't plan to actually use this model, you could even not define it.

For instance, you can achieve it With three tables (neighbourhoods, cta_trains and cta_trains_neighbourhoods) and only two models like :

```
class Neighbourhood
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cta_trains
end

class CtaTrain
  has_and_belongs_to_many :neighbourhoods
end
```

Comment: I need to be able to add associations into the join model manually.  In this case would the HABTM convention be a better association than has_many => through?

Comment: You can still define a "junction model" and the two others would be clearer.